# Telegram Bot API. How to collect images only between start and end messages?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I'm writing Telegram bot (nodejs) which will collect all images sent to it between "start" and "end" messages. I learned how to start `bot.onText(/\/start/`, but how to react on "end" message from user to start reacting after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain state for every user who is going to send you the `/start` and `/end` command. You can persist the state in a Key/Value store (e.g. `{ userid: xxx, end: false }`. You can then check against the database store every time a picture is sent. An example of how your code would look like is:

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, msg => {
    //saveToDb({chat_id: msg.chat.id, completed: false});
});


bot.onText(/\/end/, msg => {
    //saveToDb({chat_id: msg.chat.id, completed: true});
});

bot.on("message", msg => {
    // most of this code is just for logical purposes to explain the concept
    if (typeof msg.image === "object") {
       //const completed = checkDb(msg.chat.id);
       if (completed !== true) {
          // work with the image
       }
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can look into [mau](https://github.com/forfuturellc/mau) its aim is to solve this issue. It works well with `node-telegram-bot-api`, check the examples folder to get started on how it works.